# dnssec-signzone: error: dns_master_load: domain.tld.zone:3: domain.tld: not at top of zone

Tags: bind, nameserver

I'm trying to sign a NSD zone but I'm getting the following error and I don't understand why:

```
$ dnssec-keygen -a ed25519 -3 -K /etc/dnssec/mykeys/ example.com
Generating key pair.
Kexample.com.+015+06293
$ dnssec-signzone -S -K /etc/dnssec/mykeys/  /var/lib/nsd/example.com.zone
dnssec-signzone: error: dns_master_load: example.com.zone:3: example.com: not at top of zone
dnssec-signzone: fatal: failed loading zone from '/var/lib/nsd/example.com.zone': not at top of zone
```

I have the following zone:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 1800
@    IN   SOA    ns.example.com.    admin.example.com. (
                                       20210324
                                       3600
                                       900
                                       1209600
                                       1800
                                        )
srv   IN   A     94.23.xx.xx
srv   IN   AAAA  2001:xx:xx::
ns    IN   CNAME srv.example.com.
@     IN   NS    ns.example.com.
```

Comment: What did the command line look like? Does the zone name match?

Comment: By obfuscating everything you removed any useful detail, since you do not provide either the real command run. Also please do not obfuscate badly, use `example.com` or `.example` TLD if really need (and in 99.99% of cases obfuscation is not needed and creates only more problems than solutions).

Comment: I added the command and changed domain.tld by example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you simply want to use the `-o zonename` option as the file name is not the same as the zone name (the default assumption when `-o` is not used).

The error seems to be about the `SOA` record not being at the apex of the zone, which seems to make sense as `example.com` ≠ `example.com.zone`.